# Acidity of oxonium ion

Tags: acid-base, ions

How was the pKa value (-1.7) for the oxonium ion determined? Why does it correspond to the minimum pH value accessible in water? What reaction does it represent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a nice little article in the Journal of Chemical Eduction [Negative pH Does Exist](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed083p1465) pointing out examples of negative pHs in water, for example pH = -3.6 in mine water in California.  So -1.7 is not the lowest possible pH in water. Keep in mind that pH is defined in terms of hydrogen ion activity rather than concentration.  This is emphasized in [Paradoxes: Demonstrating That It Is Not True That pH ≡ -log[H+]](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed083p752).  At high acid concentation, hydrogen ion [activity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_activity) greatly deviates from hydrogen ion concentration.  For example, in 16 molar HCl, hydrogen ion activity is 678!

And see [Negative pH and Extremely Acidic Mine Waters from Iron Mountain, California](http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1488&context=usgsstaffpub) (no paywall), which describes pH values even below -4.

In [Hydronium ion activity in strongly acidic media. Remarkable agreement between independent estimates](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00790a076) Am. Chem. Soc. vol. 95, pp 3055–3057, 70% sulfuric acid is found to have a pH of -9.8 (negative 9.8)!

However, ignoring activity and the true definition of pH, considering that pure water has a concentration of 55M, if all the water molecules were instead hydronium ions, -log(55) = -1.7.  Then in articles like [Who Knows the Ka Values of Water and the Hydronium Ion?](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed063p473) this value is attributed to the pKa of hydronium, with the supposed justification that:
$K_a = \frac{[\ce{H3O+}][\ce{H2O}]}{[\ce{H3O+}]} = [\ce{H2O}]$

The article [New point of view on the meaning and on the values of
Ka(H3O+, H2O) and Kb(H2O, OH-) pairs in water](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlepdf/1998/AN/A705491B) is a serious consideration of the true meaning of the pKa of hydronium, and points out that the -1.7 value for the pKa of hydronium has no justification.

In conclusion, pH can be below -1.7 and the pK of hydronium isn't really -1.7.

Comment: How is -3.6 possible? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Marko, OK, I added to the answer, basically because hydrogen ion activity greatly deviates from hydrogen ion concentration in concentrated acids and pH is defined as -log of hydrogen ion acitivity, not concentration.

Comment: Sadly, can't access the: Paradoxes: Demonstrating That It Is Not True That pH ≡ -log[H+].

Comment: @Marko As a substitute see http://community.asdlib.org/imageandvideoexchangeforum/2013/07/31/activity-vs-concentration/ which illustrates one of the paradoxes: that [H+] can be cut in half, yet hydrogen ion activity increases is a given example

Comment: Another example, just check the wikipedia page for HCl http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrochloric_acid and you can see that you can "easily" reach negative pH.

Comment: @Babounet the Wikipedia table isn't correct, the pHs are really even more negative than that at high concentration

Comment: Negative sure, but I am interested in less than -1.7.

Comment: @Marko OK, see http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1488&context=usgsstaffpub should be no paywall, has pH -4 and below, I'll add it to answer

Comment: Why does the activity coefficient increase, when the concentration increases? Is it because of triple ions formation?

Comment: @Marko You have to study Debye-Huckel theory and further advances of that theory.  Activity coefficients initially decrease with increasing ionic strength, go through a minimum and then increase sharply.

Answer (score 1):

> How was the pKa value (-1.7) for the oxonium ion determined?
>
> Why does it correspond to the minimum pH value accessible in water water?

Note that an oxonium ion is simply an ion in which an oxygen carries a positive formal charge. Many oxonium ions exist. One of which is hydronium ion.

The hydronium ion corresponds to the strongest acid able to exist in water for significant periods of time because a stronger acid will be immediately deprotonated by some base in the system. In other words, hydronium ion can exist in equilibrium with water.

$\ce{H3O+ + H2O <=> H3O+ + H2O}$

The reaction of a stronger acid with water will however favor the products.

$\ce{HCl + H2O -> H3O+ + Cl-}$